# randomly select rows based on limited random numbers

Tags: r

Seems simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a bunch of animal location data (217 individuals) as a single dataframe.  I'm trying to randomly select X locations per individual for further analysis with the caveat that X is within the range of 6-156.

So I'm trying to set up a loop that first randomly selects a value within the range of 6-156 then use that value (say 56) to randomly extract 56 locations from the first individual animal and so on.

```
for(i in unique(ANIMALS$ID)){
  sub<-sample(6:156,1)
sub2<-i([sample(nrow(i),sub),])
}
```

This approach didn't seem to work so I tried tweaking it...

```
for(i in unique(ANIMALS$ID)){
  sub<-sample(6:156,1)
  rand<-i[sample(1:nrow(i),sub,replace=FALSE),]
}
```

This did not work either.. Any suggestions or previous postings would be helpful!

Head of the datafile...ANIMALS is the name of the df, ID indicates unique individuals

```
>  FID      X       Y MONTH DAY YEAR HOUR MINUTE SECOND  ELKYR SOURCE ID animalid   
1   0 510313 4813290     9   5 2008   22     30      0 342008     FG  1        1    
2   1 510382 4813296     9   6 2008    1     30      0 342008     FG  1        1    
3   2 510385 4813311     9   6 2008    2      0      0 342008     FG  1        1   
4   3 510385 4813394     9   6 2008    3     30      0 342008     FG  1        1 
5   4 510386 4813292     9   6 2008    2     30      0 342008     FG  1        1
6   5 510386 4813431     9   6 2008    4      1      0 342008     FG  1        1
```

Comment: can you show part of your data? Maybe `dput(head(ID))` ?

Comment: First off, is `ANIMALS` the name of the dataFrame or is it `ID`?  The way you have your `unique()` statement set up, `ID` is the name of the dataframe and you're running across the `ANIMALS` vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `mapply`. This function takes two lists (or something that can be coerced into a list) and applies function `FUN` to corresponding elements.

```
# simulate some data
xy <- data.frame(animal = rep(1:10, each = 10), loc = runif(100))

# calculate number of samples for individual animal
num.samples.per.animal <- sample(3:6, length(unique(xy$animal)), replace = TRUE)

num.samples.per.animal
 [1] 6 3 4 4 6 3 3 6 3 5

# subset random x number of rows from each animal
result <- do.call("rbind", 
                  mapply(num.samples.per.animal, split(xy, f = xy$animal), FUN = function(x, y) {
                    y[sample(1:nrow(y), x),]
                  }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
)
result

    animal        loc
7        1 0.99483999
1        1 0.50951321
10       1 0.36505294
6        1 0.34058842
8        1 0.26489107
9        1 0.47418823
13       2 0.27213396
12       2 0.28087775
15       2 0.22130069
23       3 0.33646632
21       3 0.02395097
28       3 0.53079981
29       3 0.85287600
35       4 0.84534073
33       4 0.87370167
31       4 0.85646813
34       4 0.11642335
46       5 0.59624723
48       5 0.15379729
45       5 0.57046122
42       5 0.88799675
44       5 0.62171858
49       5 0.75014593
60       6 0.86915983
54       6 0.03152932
56       6 0.66128549
64       7 0.85420774
70       7 0.89262455
68       7 0.40829671
78       8 0.19073661
72       8 0.20648832
80       8 0.71778913
73       8 0.77883677
75       8 0.37647108
74       8 0.65339300
82       9 0.39957202
85       9 0.31188471
88       9 0.10900795
100     10 0.55282999
95      10 0.10145296
96      10 0.09713218
93      10 0.64900866
94      10 0.76099256
```

*EDIT*

Here is another (more straightforward) approach that also handles cases when number of rows is less than the number of samples that should be allocated.

```
set.seed(357)
result <- do.call("rbind",
                  by(xy, INDICES = xy$animal, FUN = function(x) {
                    avail.obs <- nrow(x)

                    num.rows <- sample(3:15, 1)
                    while (num.rows > avail.obs) {
                      message("Sample to be larger than available data points, repeating sampling.")
                      num.rows <- sample(3:15, 1)
                    }
                    x[sample(1:avail.obs, num.rows), ]
                  }))
result
```

Comment: Hi Roman,Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: I should add that the number of rows vary among individual animals.

Comment: @odocoileus I've added another solution which accommodates cases when there are less points than desired by the sample. Another way to handle this would be to take all the available points. If you decide to go that way, I'll leave that to you as an exercise to write the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I like Stackoverflow because I learn so much.  @RomanLustrik provided a simple solution; mine is straight-froward as well:

```
# simulate some data
xy <- data.frame(animal = rep(1:10, each = 10), loc = runif(100))

newVec <- NULL #Create a blank dataFrame

for(i in unique(xy$animal)){
  #Sample a number between 1 and 10 (or 6 and 156, if you need)
    samp <- sample(1:10, 1) 
  #Determine which rows of dataFrame xy correspond with unique(xy$animal)[i]
    rows <- which(xy$animal == unique(xy$animal)[i]) 
  #From xy, sample samp times from the rows associated with unique(xy$animal)[i]
    newVec1 <- xy[sample(rows, samp, replace = TRUE), ]
  #append everything to the same new dataFrame 
    newVec <- rbind(newVec, newVec1) 
  }
```

Comment: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument  hmm...I thought maybe there were individuals that had less than 156 rows that were messing up the analysis so I removed (n = 3), and reran analysis...still got the same error message...any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `length(x)`?

Comment: length(x) = object not found

Comment: length(xy), from your example = 13

Comment: I only changed the df and column header (from xy$animal to elk$elkID)

Comment: Did you replace all instances of `xy` with `elk` and `$animals` with `$elkID`, including the third row of the `for()` loop?